# How to run a command as root in python?

Tags: python, linux, selenium, keyboard, root

I have a Selenium script that needed to use the "keyboards" library, but it won't work without root. How can I run it as root?

```
keyboard.send('mytext')
```

> Error: "You must be root to use this library on linux."

Comment: Run the script as root: `sudo python script.py`, but make sure that you know what the script does. I.e., if there's `os.system("rm -rf /"), don't run it as root.

Comment: This option won't work because if I run the whole script as root and not that line, then the script won't see the chrome driver.

Error :
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package requires root permissions and root access. So, it must run as root and the package must be installed as root.

*sudo* commands are useful for this.

**sudo python selenium_script.py**
will run it as root. If this alone does not solve, you must install it as root too. Navigate to your terminal and **cd** to working directory (or home directory). Then, run this command:

**sudo pip3 install keyboard**  # use pip if on python 2